# What are the pitfalls in when moving a 8.5.2 XPages application to 8.5.3

Tags: xpages

Any suggestions on what to look for before moving to 8.5.3?

For example XSP.partialRefreshGet or XSP.partialRefreshPost commands should take a second parameter (even an empty one) after 8.5.3.

Are there any other known things to check for ?

Comment: Fredrik, I edited the question to be better understood :)

Answer (score 2):

[Heads up for upgraders : 8.5.3 cannot support > 1 rich text editor per xpage if the image upload feature is used.](http://www.seancull.co.uk/public/seancull.nsf/dx/8.5.3-cannot-support-1-rich-text-editor-per-xpage-if-the-image-upload-feature-is-used..htm)

Answer (score 1):

After 8.5.2 (not 8.5.3!), viewScope should be getting serializable variables by default.

http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/serialization-viewscope-and-exploding-xpage-after-upgrade....htm

After 8.5.3, Custom control and XPage elements will not accept "-" character in their names. Existing ones continue to work but you may not create new ones.

Comment: Serialization of the viewScope was added in 8.5.2, so if your app is working in 8.5.2, it will not break in 8.5.3... at least, not for this reason.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my mistake. I am not keeping up versions anymore :)